# Return value from javascript function on the basis of Json function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, validation

I have JS code something like shown below:

```
function ValidateBid(source, args) {
            var txtValue = $('#txtBid').val();
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                async: true,
                url: "BidDetail.aspx/ValidateValue", 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{value:" + JSON.stringify(txtValue) + "}", 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var resultAsJson = msg.d // your return result is JS array
                    args.IsValid = msg.d;

                    // Now you can loop over the array to get each object
                }
            });
            return args.IsValid;
        }
```

Here what happens is, it returns args.IsValid first and then it goes into the method args.IsValid. I have used `CustomValidator` and i am calling this function on its `ClientValidationFunction`.

What i want is, i want to return `true` or `false` on the basis of what Json Function `ValidateValue` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is async so it will return value before it is set. So I think if you change `async:false` will work.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to return a value you get from an asynchronous call from the function wherein that call is situated; your function will end before the asynchronous call returns.

so...use a callback:

```
function callback(result) {
    // do womething with that result
}

function ValidateBid(source, args, callback) {
    // do ajax stuff
    // when you get the result from your ajax call do:
    callback(result);
}
```